# Go Unpacking Array As Arguments

Tags: go, argument-unpacking

So in Python and Ruby there is the splat operator (*) for unpacking an array as arguments. In Javascript there is the .apply() function. Is there a way of unpacking an array/slice as function arguments in Go? Any resources for this would be great as well!

Something along the lines of this:

```
func my_func(a, b int) (int) {
    return a + b
}

func main() {
    arr := []int{2,4}
    sum := my_func(arr)
}
```

Comment: First of all, `arr` is not an array. It is a *slice*.

Answer (score 275, accepted):

You can use a vararg syntax similar to C:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func my_func( args ...int) int {
   sum := 0
   for _,v := range args {
      sum = sum + v
   }

   return sum;
}

func main() {
    arr := []int{2,4}
    sum := my_func(arr...)
    fmt.Println("Sum is ", sum)
}
```

Now you can sum as many things as you'd like. Notice the important `...` after when you call the `my_func` function.

Running example: http://ideone.com/8htWfx

Comment: `...` works for `slices`. Do we have something similar for type `array`?

Comment: @Yogesh I may be a bit late, but you could always do something like `arr := [3]int{1, 2, 3}; my_func(arr[:]...)`, which turns it into a slice and then unpacks it.

Comment: how we can handle that when function expect ```...interface{}``` and our slice is  another type

Answer (score 19):

Either your function is varargs, in which you can use a slice with the `...` notation as Hunter McMillen shows, or your function has a fixed number of arguments and you can unpack them when writing your code.

If you really want to do this dynamically on a function of fixed number of arguments, you can use reflection:

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "reflect"

func my_func(a, b int) (int) {
    return a + b
}

func main() {
    arr := []int{2,4}
    var args []reflect.Value
    for _, x := range arr {
        args = append(args, reflect.ValueOf(x))
    }
    fun := reflect.ValueOf(my_func)
    result := fun.Call(args)
    sum := result[0].Interface().(int)
    fmt.Println("Sum is ", sum)
}
```

Comment: I'm curious to see how this benchmarks against the varargs approach. I would assume it would perform less efficiently, but I'll have to look into it.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen did you get any insight about performance comparison?

Comment: @AkiRoss probably, but it was so long ago that I have forgotten the results :|

Comment: lol ok, not a big deal: I suppose it's slower anyway, maybe I'll run some tests myself. Thanx

Comment: sum := result[0].Interface().(int) --> what is this syntax do?

Comment: @Krishnaps: Look at the documentation of `reflect.Value`'s `Call()` method. It returns a slice of `Value`s, corresponding to multiple return values in Go. `result` is this slice of `Value`s. Assuming we are only dealing with functions that return one value, we just take the first one (`result[0]`), calls the `Interface()` method to obtain the underlying value of the `reflect.Value`, and then asserts it to the return type we expect (in this case `int`).

Answer (score -4):

https://play.golang.org/p/2nN6kjHXIsd

I had a reason to unpack some vars from a map[string]string with single quotes around some of them as well as without. Here's the logic for it and the play link up top has the full working snippet.

```
func unpack(a map[string]string) string {

var stmt, val string
var x, y []string
for k, v := range a {
    x = append(x, k)
    y = append(y, "'"+v+"'")
}

stmt = "INSERT INTO tdo.rca_trans_status (" + strings.Join(x, ", ")
val = ") VALUES (" + strings.Join(y, ",") + ");"

return stmt + val}
```

Which presents cleanly for a mssql query as:

```
INSERT INTO tdo.rca_trans_status (rca_json_body, original_org, md5sum, updated, rca_key) VALUES ('blob','EG','2343453463','2009-11-10 23:00:00','prb-180');
```

Comment: This is a classic setup for SQL injection, SO doesn't let me vote on answers but you should not use this for SQL statement preparation and instead use database/sql https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql

Comment: `unpack(map[string]string{ "id": "NULL); DROP TABLE tdo.rca_trans_status; --" })`

Comment: Please use https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.Prepare to create prepared statement and to avoid SQL injection problems.

Answer (score -26):

No, there's no direct support for this in the language. Python and Ruby, as well as Javascript you're mentioning; are all dynamic/scripting languages. Go is way closer to, for example, C than to any dynamic language. The 'apply' functionality is handy for dynamic languages, but of little use for static languages like C or Go,

Comment: @user7610 you are wrong. You are reffering to different case than in question. In original question there is no variadic parameter in function declaration.

Comment: Yeah, I was, I guess. What Python/Ruby does can be thought of as syntactic sugar for the reflective call that Go supports...